# What is the difference between IIS and Visual Studio IIS in Web Requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpwebrequest

I am trying to run a custom site on IIS with ASP.NET whih connects to a site on the internet which is a coding community via HttpWebRequest.

If I use the Visual Studio built-in Development Server it successfully runs and shows the result of the Request.

But as soon as I use the local IIS for running the application I get an error saying that the site (which I am trying to connect to) is refusing the connection.

But there has nothing changed right? I have not changed my code at all!

EDIT: My understanding is that the IIS and VIsual Studio's "On-The-Run" IIS are in base the same. But why are they acting so different here?

Answer (score -2):

Web applications in a production environment are hosted using Microsoft's IIS web server software. In the development environment, however, the application may be hosted using IIS or the ASP.NET Development Server. Ideally, the same web server software should be used in both environments because using different software adds another variable in the mix. However, the ease of use of the ASP.NET Development Server makes it an attractive choice in the development environment. The good news is that there are only a few fundamental differences between IIS and the ASP.NET Development Server, and if you are aware of these differences you can take steps to help ensure that the application works and functions the same way regardless of the environment.

Comment: yeah. and what are the differences?

Answer (score -2):

Visual studio uses IIS Express to host your application, which is a lightweight, self-contained version of IIS. **It is used by developers to develop and test websites inside the same machine(localhost)**. The major difference between IIS and IIS express is that IIS express **doesn't** accept request outside the localhost. while IIS accept the web request from any another machine inside the domain. SO in order to accept request from your application you have to deploy it to IIS not IIS express.